# Git: how to amend an old merge (in a series of merges)?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have a situation that sort of looks like this:

```
(branch 1) A -- B -- C
                      \
(dev br)     E -- F -- G -- H
                 /         /
(branch 2) I -- J -- K -- L
```

This all worked fine. Unfortunately I figured out that I need to make a change to F (post commit between J and E), so I'm trying to accomplish the following:

```
(branch 1) A -- B -- C
                      \
(dev br)     E -- F' -- G -- H
                 /         /
(branch 2) I -- J -- K -- L
```

My initial approach was to make another commit with the fixes on the `dev br` and do a rebase and squash it into F. However, this makes me resolve all merge conflicts from the C-G merge and the L-H merge again, which were fairly involved and I don't want to do them.

Next attempt, I basically checked out F, made my changes, and then cherry picked G on top. This made the correct changes and I didn't have to resolve too much. However, now git doesn't think that this is a merge (because I guess it was cherry picked, though I did supply the -m command). Is there a way not to lose the merge info?

I tried it with rebase as well, running it as `git rebase --onto F' C G`, but that also makes me go through all previous commits (A-C, but in reality there are many more) and solve their rebase conflicts again.

How do I do this without going insane? I'm sure there must be a proper way to do this.

Comment: More out of morbid curiosity than anything else: why do you need to do this? Is there some specific outcome that couldn't be achieved by just tacking on the change after `H`?

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz, well I messed up merge F (I accepted a change from J that I shouldn't have), so I don't want to commit an essentially broken merge (this is for work and we do code review, soooo...). However, if there is no easy way to do it, I'll just tack it on at the end .

Comment: TBH, I'd recommend just resolving the messed-up bit at the end in a new commit after `H`. It'll be easier, and you won't go messing around with history (which might have unintended consequences). Just include an apologetic commit message and buy a round of doughnuts for your team, if what you broke was that bad :P

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz, *sigh* I might just have to do that honestly. I'll give it until tomorrow to see if anyone knows any sweet git tricks.

Comment: This does not help for the current case, but for the future you might want to have a look at [git rerere](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html) which remembers your conflict solutions and applies them if the conflict happens again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'll give it until tomorrow to see if anyone knows any sweet git tricks.

OK: one "Git trick" for you.
From what you describe, the cherry-pick is the most promising approach.

> "However, now Git doesn't think that this is a merge".

But it can.

After having modify `F` into `F'`:

- make your cherry-pick *without* committing right away:

  ```
  git cherry-pick --no-commit -m 1 vG
  git stash
  ```
- add the merge information (without redoing any merge, with the `ours` strategy)

  ```
  git merge -s ours -m "Gp" branch1
  git stash pop
  git commit --amend --no-edit
  ```

That will create a `G'` (`G` prime, or `Gp`), which records a merge from `branch1`, while keeping the result of the cherry-pick intact.

You might have to repeat that for `H`, and you are done.

(The [OP Catsunami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6191539/catsunami) mentioned below [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219179/git-how-to-amend-an-old-merge-in-a-series-of-merges/39220910#comment65808494_39220910) the need for `git stash` in order to allow for the merge to proceed)

Comment: Ooh that sounds very promising, I will try it out when I get in to work today and report back. Thank you!

Comment: That worked wonderfully. After the cherry-pick I wasn't able to do the merge until I stashed the changes. So I basically ended up doing cherry-pick -> stash -> merge with ours -> stash pop -> amend commit.

Comment: @Catsunami Great! I have integrated your comment in the answer for more visibility.